# Find value of a key within a list of dictionary given the key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to get ['a','b'] from the following variables in Python:

```
mylist = [{'A': ['a','b']}, {'B': ['c','d']}]
```

and

```
keys = ['A']
```

I have seen various questions with answers using itemgetter but this would only work when the keys of the dictionaries within the list are the same. (If I use itemgetter on my data, it will return me a KeyError)

Does anyone know how I could make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Depends. Do you just need to do a one time lookup or several? For a one time lookup it's not worth building an extra data structure

Answer (score 1):

I'd turn `mylist` into a single dictionary:

```
In [27]: d = dict(reduce(operator.add, (x.items() for x in mylist)))
```

and then query it like so:

```
In [28]: [d[k] for k in keys]
Out[28]: [['a', 'b']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want this:

```
mylist[0][keys[0]]
```

This is because your dictionary is placed in a list, so you need to get it out first like so: `mylist[0]`. You can then index the dictionary with the string `'A'`, which is also be the first element of a list, i.e. `keys[0]`. Putting the two together, you arrive at the highlighted statement above.

Comment: Sorry, I havent explained properly: The example above is very simplified, in my scenario, I dont know where the positions of the dictionary with the key defined in keys are, so it wouldnt be possible to rely on indices to get the values I want.

Comment: Ah fair enough, so there is no "clever" way of doing this?

Comment: Do you want all the values that have the string 'A' as a key in any of your dictionaries?

Comment: That would be desirable (but shouldn't happen in my case)